# Using SQL Express 2008 with VS2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I have the following installed:

- VS 2008 SP 1
- ASP.NET MVC 1.0
- SQL Express 2008
- SQL Management Studio 2008 (for connecting to SQL2008 Server)

When I right click on the App_Data Directory and click "Add New Item", if I choose SQL Server Database and name the .MDB file, I get an error:

> *Connections to SQL Server Files*
>   *(*.mdf) require SQL Server Express*
>   *2005 to function properly.  Please*
>   *verify the installation of the*
>   *component or download from the URL...*

What's up with that?  Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it x64 Vista?  This is a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361718).  The workarounds suggest there might be a hotfix (http://support.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=957944).

Answer (score 0):

[This forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/939139.aspx) suggests a fix.  It says:

> Try deleting the directory SQLEXPRESS
>   (Or better rename it say SQLEXPRESS_).
>
> It solved my problem. This directory
>   is at following location...
>
> C:\Documents and
>   Settings[USERNAME]\Local
>   Settings\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
>   Data\SQLEXPRESS
>
> Also, make sure that you preference to
>   the database is "sqlexpress" in the
>   WMD (It should be , by default).
>
> Look at
>   http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/showpost.aspx?postid=98346&siteid=1